# Use Select data in nested Select statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have a query in MySQL.

**Full Query**

```
SELECT 
  tc.expense AS expense,
  tc.tour_sub_code,
  tc.login_id

FROM
  tc_wallet tc 
WHERE tc.login_id = 'vinod.kumbala' 
  AND tc.expense = 'Daily Allowance' 
  AND tc.delete_flag = 'F' 
  AND tc.status != 'reject'
```

**Result**

```
Expense              Tour_sub_code          login_id 

DAILY ALLOWANCE       MOS-EUROPE100119      vinod.kumbala
DAILY ALLOWANCE       Test                  vinod.kumbala
```

Initially I am fetching data from `tc_wallet` table.
Now my requirement is that I need to find the total count of attendances for a particular `tour_sub_code`. Attendances count can be found from `attendance_master` table for *that* particular `tour_sub_code`.
So I included a nested select query which is

**Nested select**

```
(SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
  FROM
    (SELECT 
      * 
    FROM
      `attendance_master` 
    WHERE `delete_flag` = 'F' 
      AND login_id = 'vinod.kumbala' 
      AND `tour_sub_code` = tc.`tour_sub_code` 
    GROUP BY `device_date`) t1) AS newNoOfdays
```

**Full Query**

```
SELECT 
      tc.expense AS expense,
      tc.tour_sub_code,
      tc.login_id,
      (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
      FROM
        (SELECT 
          * 
        FROM
          `attendance_master` 
        WHERE `delete_flag` = 'F' 
          AND login_id = 'vinod.kumbala' 
          AND `tour_sub_code` = tc.`tour_sub_code` 
        GROUP BY `device_date`) t1) AS newNoOfdays 

    FROM
      tc_wallet tc 
    WHERE tc.login_id = 'vinod.kumbala' 
      AND tc.expense = 'Daily Allowance' 
      AND tc.delete_flag = 'F' 
      AND tc.status != 'reject'
```

Now this query gives me error as

> Unknown column 'tc.tour_sub_code' in 'where clause'

**Expected Result**

```
Expense              Tour_sub_code          login_id            Count

    DAILY ALLOWANCE       MOS-EUROPE100119      vinod.kumbala     20
    DAILY ALLOWANCE       Test                  vinod.kumbala     44
```

Can I know where I am going wrong with this ?
Also is there any other way i get result like by using JOINS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the innermost subquery you are referencing a column from the outer most query. This is not permitted for subqueries in the FROM clause (derived tables). However - You don't need that subquery. What you need is `COUNT(DISTINCT device_date)`

Rewrite

```
(SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
  FROM
    (SELECT 
      * 
    FROM
      `attendance_master` 
    WHERE `delete_flag` = 'F' 
      AND login_id = 'vinod.kumbala' 
      AND `tour_sub_code` = tc.`tour_sub_code` 
    GROUP BY `device_date`) t1) AS newNoOfdays
```

to

```
(SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT device_date)
  FROM `attendance_master` 
  WHERE `delete_flag` = 'F' 
    AND login_id = 'vinod.kumbala' 
    AND `tour_sub_code` = tc.`tour_sub_code` 
) AS newNoOfdays
```

You can also rewrite the full query to a LEFT JOIN query:

```
SELECT 
  tc.expense AS expense,
  tc.tour_sub_code,
  tc.login_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT device_date) AS newNoOfdays 
FROM tc_wallet tc
LEFT JOIN attendance_master am
  ON  am.tour_sub_code = tc.tour_sub_code
  AND am.delete_flag = 'F' 
  AND am.login_id = 'vinod.kumbala' 
WHERE tc.login_id = 'vinod.kumbala' 
  AND tc.expense = 'Daily Allowance' 
  AND tc.delete_flag = 'F' 
  AND tc.status != 'reject'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
      tc.expense AS expense,
      tc.tour_sub_code,
      tc.login_id,
      count(*) as count

    FROM
      tc_wallet tc
    INNER JOIN
      attendance_master am
    ON
      tc.tour_sub_code = am.tour_sub_code AND
      tc.login_id = am.login_id

    WHERE tc.login_id = 'vinod.kumbala' 
      AND tc.expense = 'Daily Allowance' 
      AND tc.delete_flag = 'F' 
      AND tc.status != 'reject'

    GROUP BY 
      tc.expense AS expense,
      tc.tour_sub_code,
      tc.login_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This ---

```
SELECT 
      tc.expense AS expense,
      tc.tour_sub_code,
      tc.login_id,
      (SELECT 
        COUNT(am.*) 
      FROM `attendance_master` as am
        WHERE am.delete_flag = 'F' 
          AND am.login_id = 'vinod.kumbala' 
          AND am.tour_sub_code = tc.tour_sub_code
        GROUP BY am.device_date) AS count 

    FROM
      tc_wallet tc 
    WHERE tc.login_id = 'vinod.kumbala' 
      AND tc.expense = 'Daily Allowance' 
      AND tc.delete_flag = 'F' 
      AND tc.status != 'reject'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
select  tc.expense AS expense,
        tc.tour_sub_code,
        tc.login_id,
        newNoOfdays.countVal
from    tc_wallet tc
inner join
        (   select  tour_sub_code, count('A') 'countval'
            from    attendance_master ascs (nolock)
            group by tour_sub_code) as newNoOfdays
on  newNoOfdays.tour_sub_code = tc.tour_sub_code
where   tc.login_id = 'vinod.kumbala' 
AND     tc.expense = 'Daily Allowance' 
AND     tc.delete_flag = 'F' 
AND     tc.status != 'reject'
```